# How to render tinymce content in a div tag using thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, tinymce, thymeleaf

I'm trying to render [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/) content in a `div` tag using [`thymeleaf`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/), but it renders all  `html` tags as text. Is there a way to render it as `html`?

```
<div th:text="${obj.description}">

</div>
```

Comment: Hello @ProNoob, could you share your code on how to load the Thymeleaf template into TinyMCE? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render html use:

```
 <div th:utext="${obj.description}">

 </div>
```

utext- unescaped text